# Медиаплеер с возможностью добавить внешние субтитры к видео youtube

Tags: youtube, mediaplayer

Основная идея сайта — перевод англоязычных песен(с видео клипами) с помощью субтитров, которые размещены на моём хостинге в формате `.vtt`. Пробовал медиаплеер `plyr`, как ни пытался, субтитры с файла он не воспроизводил.
Моя попытка подключить субтитры:

```
<div class="plyr__video-embed" id="js-player">
  <iframe
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bTqVqk7FSmY"
    allowfullscreen
    allowtransparency
    allow="autoplay"
  ></iframe>
  <track kind="captions" label="Russian captions" src="/path/to/captions.vtt" srclang="ru" default />
</div>
```

Если использовать обходной путь и скачивать видео с ютуба и вставлять на сайт как `.mp4` в `<video>`, то субтитры работают, но будут проблемы с правообладателями и размещать файлы на своём хостинге более затратно, чем подключать с ютуба.

Знаете ли вы другие медиаплееры с такой возможностью или как по-другому это можно реализовать?